# What are the advantages or disadvantages of using dbml for linq2sql queries?

Tags: linq-to-sql, entities

I am currently reading Pro Asp.Net MVC, and they are building all of their linq2sql entity classes by hand, and mapping them with the linq mapping attributes.  However, everyone else I see (from google searches) talking about linq 2 sql seem to be using the visual designer for building all of their entities.  Which is the preferred way to build l2s entities, and what are the advantages/disadvantages of each?

The only difference I have noticed so far, is I can't seem to do inheritance mapping when using the visual designer, although MSDN says I should be able to so I might just be missing it in VS 2010's interface.  However, I'm not so sure I should use inheritance anyway as that could technically add additional joins when I don't need the sub table data.

As a PS, l2s will not be doing any modification of my schema, I will be generating schema changes manually and then replicating them in linq2sql.

Thanks,

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We used the designer all the time.  It indeed introduces an added step, every time you make a change to the schema you need to import the table into the designer again, but I think that effrot pales in comparison to the amount of code you need to write if you bypass the desginer.

Also note that the designer creates partial classes, you can create an additional file for the partial class that includes additional implementation details.  That way, when the table gets refereshed in the designer, it leaves you additional code alone.  We do this to add a lot of helper functions to the classes, and also to provide strictly typed enumerated properties that overlay the primitive integer FK fields.

It's true that inheritance would be very difficult to accomplish well, but I think if you need that sort of data layer, L2S may not be the best solution.  I prefer to keep my data layer clean and simple, just using L2S to get the data in and out, and then pu more complicated logic in the business layer.  If we really needed to do things like object inheritance in our data layer, I would probably explore a more advanced and complicated technology like EF

Answer (score 1):

We've built our entire application framework backend using L2S. I developed most of the this. I started to use the DBML designer but I quickly realized this was a royal pain. Every schema change required a change to the table(s) in the designers. Plus, the entities created by the designer all get stuffed in a single class file, and didn't have all the functionality I wanted, like support for M2M relationships, and more. So, it didn't take long before I realized I wanted a better way.

I ended up writing my own code generator that generates the L2S entities the way I want them, and it also generates a "lightweight" set of entities that are used in the application layer. These don't have any L2S plumbing. The code generator creates all these entities, and other code, directly from a target database. No more DBML!

This has worked very well for us and our entities are exactly the way we want them, and generated automatically each time our database schema changes.